# 100% background to a left floated div in which another right floated div exceeds than left

Tags: html, css

HTML I used...

```
<div id="left">
   few contents here
</div>
<div id="right">
   more contents here
</div>
```

CSS I applied...

```
#left{float: left; width: 300px; background: red;}
#right{float: right; width 600px; background: green;}
```

I don't want to specify height in `#left` contents because what larger contents of `#right` contents will be? So, I have used `height: 100%;` in `#left` but it didn't work.

Comment: See **[this link](http://tutorialzy.blogspot.com/2013/03/fundamental-history.html)** to know what I actually want.

Comment: Problem viewing page? If so, See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/98/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok try this http://jsfiddle.net/7KhXd/1/

here is the html summary:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-nav">
        <!-- left nav content-->
    </div>
    <div id="main"> 
        <div>
            <!-- main body contnent-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 1000px;
}


#main {
  margin-left:20em;

  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

#main > div {
  background-color: grey; /* so that main has the same color as nav bar if necessary */
}

#left-nav {
  width: 19em;
  float: left;
}
```

**explanation:**
the idea is that you don't ant the left nav bar to be the same length as the main body.. rather you want it to *appear* as if it's the same lenght.. you achieve that by giving it a background color that extends the same length as the main body (regardless of how or short it is)..

so you have a container div (ie wrapper div) and give it a back ground color.. and create a main div and give it a left margin, in that left margin you float in the nav bar..

this way whichever of the two is longest (main or nav bar).. the other will have the same background color.. you just have to put a padding to visually seperate them

Comment: maybe i didn't understand your question right.. what is it that you want to see? do you want to see left and right the same height?

Comment: Yes! See **[this link](http://tutorialzy.blogspot.com/2013/03/fundamental-history.html)** and specify how to do for both the same height?

Comment: ok i see your problem now.. i updated my answer.. have fun :)

Comment: Yes! this method I can do, but I just wanted to know that by specifying height to 100%. Isn't there any possibility to do?

Comment: yes you can do that too.. you just have to manage the background colors so that it looks right.. ultimately you want the height to be as much as your content fills it though..

Comment: hey man that's not cool.. if you ask a certain question then get answers and accept one.. you can't go back and modify the question and take away the correct question award. If you want you can open a new question, i'll be happy to help there.. please return my award and give me a link to the new question

Comment: I'll obviously return your award after someone answer what I actually want. If another person give me right answer then also you would get vote by me. Don't hesitate please. I have just unchecked that other may answer. Ok. After you read it please delete your last comment.

Comment: anyway, as your  wish i have asked new question okey now. **[The Link is Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360102/100-height-doesnt-work)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the height of the container elements as well so try this

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GEKDN/)

Comment: I saw your demo its working but in my page it's not working why?

Comment: @C-Link Do you have this at the top `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I knew this problem, I have used this within '#wrap'. How to do?

Comment: @C-Link I've not used any wrapping element, if the parent of these divs is body than this should work

Comment: Please check **[this link](http://tutorialzy.blogspot.com/2013/03/fundamental-history.html)** and tell me how to do that I want?

Comment: @C-Link there are multiple head and body tags in your blog, just check out the source, it's very dirty

Comment: No. Just viewed that link? I want to set my background of left-nav to full height. Could you do that?

Comment: @C-Link Am at work, I just saw the source, you need to fix that first, multiple body and head tags, you are throwing html before declaring doctype, so in general it is bad

Comment: Problem viewing page? If so, See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/98/)**

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    #left {
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
        background: red;
        height:100%
    }
    #right {
        float: right;
    width 600px;
        background: green;
        height:100%
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="left"> few contents here </div>
    <div id="right"> more contents here </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in CSS we need the height of either side to be fixed/known...
However there's still lots of roundabouts out there.
**Solution:** Use the border of one side as the background of the the other side.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    #container { width: 800px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
    #wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        border-left: 200px solid #efacec;
    }
    #left {
        float: left;
        width: 160px;
        margin-left: -190px;
        margin-right: 200px;
        position: relative;            
    }
    #right {
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="left">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is awesome! but I need to design like **[this link](http://tutorialzy.blogspot.com/2013/03/fundamental-history.html)**