# 100% height doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

```
+----------------------+
|          1           |
|                      |
+----------------------+
|       |              |
|   2   |              |
|       |              |
|       |      4       |
+-------|              |
|    3  |              |
|       |              |
+----------------------+
```

As shown above (1) I need to add some header contents, (2) left navigation, (3) some content within 2 to center of 3 but don't know the height because of 4, (4) larger contents . Hence, I need to specify `height: 100%;` but doesn't work. How to do?

**Edit**

```
<div id="wrap">
<!--contents of (1)--> 
</div>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="left-nav">
<!--contents of (2)-->
<div id="someid">
<!-contents of (3)-->
</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
<!--contents of (4)-->
</div>
</div>
```

main css i want to use background (2)&(3) same, background of (4) different.

```
#left-nav{width: 200px; background-color: red; height: 100%;}
```

**[chek this link](http://tutorialzy.blogspot.com/2013/03/fundamental-history.html)** the red text with red border is what i want to give the `height: 100%;`

Comment: You can specify `min-height` or try specifying `height` for the `body,html` class also.

Comment: don't give 100% height, 100% means screen height, and your large content may b larger than your screen, give it a height:auto. though in case of no content or little content, it will have no height

Comment: that true, 100% for height won't work. Try below like 90 - 99%

Comment: Can you please post an example code where you try it and it does not work? You will get a good answer faster.

Comment: when you say 2 to center of 3.. you mean the content included in `div 2` must be horizontally centered with the content of `div 3`? if so what does the height gotta do with that? if you show us what you've tried.. and then highlight the broken part.. we can give you the answer you're looking for

Comment: and so you mean that the advertisement must take the remaining space left between 2 and 4? said another way.. if 4 was 1000px and 2 was 300px, then the height of the advertisement (ie div 3) must be the difference = 1000-300= 700px?

Comment: Yes! but I may not know the height of 4. because sometimes it may contain smaller or sometime it may contain larger.

Comment: can the answer contain javascript? or just css?

Comment: @abbood- just css only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nice to see the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15376558/2129835) in it's entirety :)

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9cSZ/8/)

When you have dynamic content and you don't know how tall your page is going to be, you should not set the `height` property since the height will set it relative to either the parent (or window)'s height. Again, we want the size to be dynamic! So don't set the height property.

I think the question could be rephrased to:

> *Q: How can you make dynamic areas the same height with **only CSS**?*

To put it simply, you **can't**. But, you can make them *appear* to be the same height.

This is a pure CSS implementation that will probably not look quite right in < IE8. I'll expand off of [@Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15400702/2129835).

1. Wrap the sidebar elements in a new div (`#sidebar`) and again, `float:
   left`.
2. Set `#wrap { overflow: auto }`, this will allow `#wrap` to expand to contain `#sidebar` in the event that it becomes taller than `#main`. [(Source)](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)
3. Set `#sidebar { width: X }` and `#main { padding-right: X }`. This will make it so `#main` respect's the area on the left that will be taken up by the `#sidebar`'s background.
4. The final part is setting up the background for `#sidebar` and `#main`. We'll do this by setting **two** background images: `#wrap { background: url('image1') repeat-y, 
               url('image2') X 0 }`, where X is the width of the sidebar. Make sure the image is the same width as the sidebar and only repeat it in the y-direction. The 2nd image will be offset to the right of the sidebar and tiled to fill the rest of `#wrap`'s background.

Since neither `#sidebar` nor `#main` have a set height they are free to expand as their content grows. We fixed `#wrap` to expand to the height of the floated `#sidebar`, and it will normally expand to cover the height of `#main` since it is just a normal block element. Because the backgrounds are set to `#wrap`, we give the **appearance** that both children are the same height as the parent.

**HTML** *(Added `#sidebar`)*

```
<div id="header">1</div>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="left-nav">2</div>
        <div id="someid">3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

*NOTE: Multiple images will not work < IE8. You can still set a color to `#main`, but it will not expand to the height of `#wrap` if `#sidebar` is **taller** than `#main`.*

```
#wrap {
    background: url('image1') repeat-y, 
                url('image2') X 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: X;
}

#main {
    margin-left: X;
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me about multiple images in more?

Comment: But I want to be 3 in vertically middle, how could I do?

Comment: But still what I wanted is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

When you set something to 100%, it's 100% of the parent element. So what is the height of the parent element? If that's not set to some value, then you may not get what you are expecting. If the parent is set to 100%, ask yourself, "100% of what? What is the parent set to?" Percent won't give you a size until you get to something of value which may only be the viewport and the size of the html element.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem this way.....

```
#left-nav{position: absolute; width: 329px; height: 100%;}
#someid{height: 70%; bottom: 0;}
```

But still proper solution is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use equalizeCols (a jQuery plugin) to make both columns the same height

-or-

Simulate the look of the left bar by wrapping 3 and 4 in a container div and giving a background image with a different color/pattern on the left side that can repeat-y for the entire height of the content. Make sense?