# How to fill 100% of remaining height?

Tags: html, css, height, fill

```
+--------------------+
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|         1          |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|         2          |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

Contents of (1) as shown above are unknown, as it may increase or decrease in dynamically generated pages. The second div (2) as shown above, should fill the remaining space.

here is an example of my html

```
<div id="full">
<!--contents of 1 -->
<div id="someid">
<!--contents of 2 -->
</div>
</div>
```

css...

```
#full{width: 300px; background-color: red;}
#someid{height: 100%;}
```

Or is this method wrong? How should I do this?
please see my **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/99/)** and show me my mistake.

Comment: Do you want the height of 1 + 2 to be the exact height of the viewport? Or 2 is the same size as the viewport and it scrolls down equal to the height of 1?

Comment: height of 1 I don't know, and remaining of 1 then 2 be full height.

Comment: @C-Link What do you mean by `height:100%` ? Do you mean the div should occupy the remaining height?

Comment: @Mr_Green yes! remaining height.

Comment: @C-Link remaining height of the page or the remaining scrollheight inside the page?

Comment: @Mr_Green It would be ok in both condition.

Comment: @C-Link I can't help you but just update your question so that others can help you. From next time please explain your post clearly.. :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You should be able to do this if you add in a div (`#header` below) to wrap your contents of 1.

1. If you float `#header`, the content from `#someid` will be forced to flow around it.
2. Next, you set `#header`'s width to 100%. This will make it expand to fill the width of the containing div, `#full`. This will effectively push all of `#someid`'s content below `#header` since there is no room to flow around the sides anymore.
3. Finally, set `#someid`'s height to 100%, this will make it the same height as `#full`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9cSZ/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="full">
    <div id="header">Contents of 1</div>
    <div id="someid">Contents of 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
html, body, #full, #someid {
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

**Update**

I think it's worth mentioning that flexbox is well supported across modern browsers today. The CSS could be altered have `#full` become a flex container, and `#someid` should set it's flex grow to a value greater than `0`.

```css
html, body, #full {
  height: 100%;
}

#full {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#someid {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: please se my **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/99/) and rectify it where is mistake.

Comment: I think you are right but my problem couldn't be solved but anyway this helped me to understand about this. So I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Your answer works beautifully, but I am slightly confused as to why it works: If you play with the background colors, you can see that `#someid` is ALWAY equal to the height of `#full`, despite the height of `#header`. Logically, the content of `#someid` should start at the top of `#full`. Why does `#header` push the content down?

Comment: Well, it works beautifully until you try giving a child of `#someid` a height of 100%.

Comment: The problem with this is it makes `#someid` the same height as `#full`, so `#someid` overflows `#full` by the height of `#header`. It doesn't set `#someid` to 100% of the _remaining_ space. If you set `overflow: scroll;` on `#someid` you would see the problem.

Comment: Yeah, this answer should be updated. It was a hack that abused the fact that float pushed content down, which was a "good enough" at the time when dealing with browsers that didn't support things like `calc` and `flexbox` layouts weren't widely supported. Look how far we've come in less than 3 years!

Comment: It's an hack, but does not solve the problem, the bottom div's height is 100% screen height and it overflows. Not the ideal solution for the problem at hand and very misleading.

Comment: JS will do it... nice alternative though.... but just in case if we have to do set any child element height based on the parent div (the second div, which is pushed to the bottom) it'll cause problems, didn't see the update though... flex is a good solution but with very less fallback.., Have to do some heavy lifting through JS

Comment: @Olof_t The flexbox solution shown here does work in IE11.

Comment: The flexbox solution here works only on IE11, all other browsers provide a scroll.

Comment: The flex solution works in 2023..

Answer (score 15):

To get a `div` to 100% height on a page, you will need to set each object on the hierarchy above the div to 100% as well. for instance:

```
html { height:100%; }
body { height:100%; }
#full { height: 100%; }
#someid { height: 100%; }
```

Although I cannot fully understand your question, I'm assuming this is what you mean.

This is the example I am working from:

```
<html style="height:100%">
    <body style="height:100%">
        <div style="height:100%; width: 300px;">
            <div style="height:100%; background:blue;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`Style` is just a replacement for the CSS which I haven't externalised.

Comment: which element do you want to be 100% height? and in relation to what?

Comment: (2) should be 100% in height. Your method may work in without wrapper but I'm using a wrapper.

Comment: if you want `someid` to also be 100% then you have to add 100% to it, and set the container to 100% too.
I've edited my question to show this.

Comment: I already said it may not work coz I use a wrapper and then setting it to 100% also don't work.

Comment: Try the example I posted, You might just be missing some thing along the hierarchy which is screwing it up.

Comment: Ok! I'm sure now you are right but din't find what happened please check this and rectify. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/99/)**

Answer (score 8):

```css
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .parent {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow:column;
        height: 100%;
        background: white;
    }

    .child-top {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        background: pink;
    }

    .child-bottom {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        background: green;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child-top">
          This child has just a bit of content
        </div>
        <div class="child-bottom">
          And this one fills the rest
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on this code-only answer? Thanks!

Comment: Hello @arkascha, I've just updated my post with a working code example. Thanks for the suggestion. Cheers.

Comment: If you put this into a React code sandbox, this doesn't work

Comment: @libby for react, you have to add the `height: 100%` for the root div too

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with tables:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr height="0%"><td>
        <div id="full">
            <!--contents of 1 -->
        </div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <div id="someid">
            <!--contents of 2 -->
        </div>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Then apply css to make someid fill the remaining space:

```
#someid {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now, I can just hear the angry shouts from the crowd, "Oh noes, he's using tables! Feed him to the lions!" Please hear me out.

Unlike the accepted answer which accomplishes nothing aside from making the container div the full height of the page, this solution makes div #2 fill the remaining space as requested in the question. If you need that second div to fill the full height allotted to it, this is currently the only way to do it.

But feel free to prove me wrong, of course! CSS is always better.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late entry but even in 2016 I am surprised by the complete lack of IE support for flex (currently 11 is the only one to support it and its majorly buggy at that http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) which from a business perspective is not great! So I think until IE is shut down the best solution and most cross-browser friendly one surely must be a JS/Jquery one?

Most sites already use Jquery and a very simple example (for my code) is:

```
$('#auto_height_item').height($(window).height() - $('#header').height());
```

You can obviously replace window and header and let the basic math do the work. Personally I'm still not convinced about flex yet...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but nowadays there is a super easy form to do that, which is CCS Grid, so let me put the divs as example:

```
<div id="full">
  <div id="header">Contents of 1</div>
  <div id="someid">Contents of 2</div>
</div>
```

then the CSS code:

```
.full{
  width:/*the width you need*/;
  height:/*the height you need*/;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100px,auto) 1fr;
 }
```

And that's it, the second row, scilicet, the someide, will take the rest of the height
because of the property 1fr, and the first div will have a min of 100px and a max of
whatever it requires.

I must say CSS has advanced a lot to make easier programmers lives.

Answer (score 0):

I added this for pages that were too short.

html:

```
<section id="secondary-foot"></section>
```

css:

```
section#secondary-foot {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried this in @BhojendraNepal's JSFiddle, but couldn't get it to work. Could you show in you own JSFiddle or describe where you added your element?

Answer (score 0):

Create a div, which contains both divs (full and someid) and set the height of that div to the following:

height: 100vh;

The height of the containing divs (full and someid) should be set to "auto".
That's all.