# CSS, overflow auto, scrolling a DIV instead of whole page

Tags: css

Simple example with div below another div, the first one displays a video with a 100% width, the other one's got some overflowing text inside.. all I want is to scroll the second div instead of a whole page:

```
<div id="bot" style="overflow:auto;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H7uhM/1/

//edit
I removed z-index because it's a leftover from the master code.
The height of video may vary, and that's why setting the #bot div to a constant height is not the solution. The video depends on a ration my have between 35%-50% of the page's height.

Comment: You may just need a `height` or `max-height`

Comment: I have added an answer, let me know if that is what you were after. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to change your style to be `overflow-y: scroll;` and you need a height otherwise the element will continue growing to accommodate the contents.

Example:

```
<div id="bot" style="overflow-y:scroll; height: 250px;">
```

*Also, the z-index was irrelevant*

**If you want to use Javascript, you can achieve your desired effect like this:**

```
<script>
window.onload = function () { 
    var bot = document.getElementById('bot');
    bot.style.height = (window.innerHeight - document.getElementById('top').offsetHeight) + "px";
}
</script>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/H7uhM/9/)

Comment: but what if I dont know the height? let's say it's something between 40%-60% of page..

Comment: Without giving the DIV some kind of limitation how would it know when to start scrolling? If you can use javascript, you could set it's height to (total viewport height - other content height) [This previous Stack Overflow question may help you out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580356/filling-remaining-vertical-space)

Comment: I was trying to avoid JS in this example but I think I would stay with it.. it doesn't look like there is a nice/easy css solution so I take your answer as a working solution. Thanks mate, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You must give a `height` to your `#bot` div

Comment: but is it possible without adding a height, let's consider that videos above may have different ratios?

Comment: @PeteKozak Without giving it a height how would it know when to start scrolling? You can use `max-height` to set the threshold. Or if you want to set your height dynamically then you could use javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, adding a height to your #bot div:

```
<div id="bot" style="overflow:auto;z-index:3;height:200px;">
```

**EDIT**

In case you want this captions container to be fluid, remember that in order to set the height of a container in percentage, its parent container needs to have an explicit height (i.e. in px for instance).

So you need you can set the height of the main container in this case in px:

```
<div id="box" style="height:600px">
```

And then you can set the height of your box in percentage:

```
  <div id="bot" style="overflow:auto;z-index:3;height:20%;">
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/H7uhM/11/

**Ps.** Another thing, I suggest you to get rid of all these inline styles for CSS.

**HTML** for structure
**CSS** for presentation
**JS** for behaviour

Keep CSS code separated from html, your code will be easy to modify and reusable.

I suggest you to read something about the concept of CSS specificity and after that you will never use inline styles again.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Is it this what you were trying to achieve? :)

Comment: but is it possible without adding a height, let's consider that videos above may have different ratios? 
yes but with a more dynamic height.. more like setting it to "auto" but that doesn't help

Comment: Ok, so you need the height to be dynamic. Let me edit my answer.