# Make 2 divs displayed vertically to fill it's parent if one of the divs is autoresize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 divs displayed vertically inside another div with `height: 100%`. The bottom div is automatically resizing it's height.

It's there a way that the first div will fill the parent in it's height?

```css
#my_app {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#top_container {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  display: table-cell;
}

#edit_container {
  margin: 20px;
  min-height: 44px;
  max-height: 80px;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #484040;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#edit {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 80px;
  overflow: scroll;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #ff5e2d;
}

#test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ff0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
  content: attr(data-text);
}

[contentEditable=true]:empty:focus:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
}

[contenteditable]:focus:after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="my_app">
  <div id="top_container">
    NEW TEST
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="edit_container">
      <form>
        <div id="edit" contenteditable="true" data-text="Insert text"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="test">
      ACTION
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RoxanaCristea/4460up4s/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify "height: 100%;" to your body element.
Have a look at this question: [How to fill 100% of remaining height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376558/how-to-fill-100-of-remaining-height)