# CSS print - stretch table for the entire page (height = 100%)

Tags: css

Basically, what I am trying to is to spread a table to fill the rest of the page in print mode. I've surfed the internet, examined [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376558/how-to-fill-100-of-remaining-height), and yet after two hours can't figure out what I am doing wrong. The idea is that the table should take up the rest of the page

```js
document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //var html = "<div>Test assignment</div>";
  //$('.test').html(html);
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
 
  #print-wrapper * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .my-table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid;
table-layout: fixed;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="print" id="print">
<div id="print-wrapper">
  <div class="print-heading">My table
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="print-week-heading">Some heading</div>
    <table class="my-table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          A
        </td>
        <td>
          B
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          C
        </td>
        <td>
          D
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `table-layout: fixed;` to table

Comment: I've added it in the question. Doesn't help

Comment: Can you clarify something for me - do you want the table to: 1. be a full page's height, or 2. fill up the remaining blank space on whatever page it's on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [vh units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) to adjust the table's height.

```
@media print {
  .my-table {
    height: 90vh; 
  }
}
```

90vh equates to 90% of the height of the page, so adjust this as necessary.

**Added code snippet:**

```js
document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //var html = "<div>Test assignment</div>";
  //$('.test').html(html);
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
 
  #print-wrapper * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .my-table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    border: solid;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="print" id="print">
<div id="print-wrapper">
  <div class="print-heading">My table
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="print-week-heading">Some heading</div>
    <table class="my-table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          A
        </td>
        <td>
          B
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          C
        </td>
        <td>
          D
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried `100vh` and the table didn't resize so I dropped that line of thought. Surprised to see `90vh` work. While experimenting with this answer I found that `height: 100vh;` and `page-break-before: always` shows the table entirely on the new page.

Comment: Could you do a code snippet showing a "working" solution?

Comment: Added a code snippet. This works for me in Chrome and Firefox, depending on your definition of "works". Admittedly there's some ambiguity in the question - should the table take up 100% of a page's height (as per the question title) or should it fill "the rest of" the page (as mentioned in the description)? My answer assumes the former; the latter is much more tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the only approach is to use `position: absolute` on the table. As long as every parent element has `height: 100%` then the table will be able to stretch to the full page height.

However, using `position: absolute` means it is now OVER the rest of the content. I have tried every combination of `page-break-*` on the table and sibling elements but cannot get the table on its own page at full height.

```js
document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //var html = "<div>Test assignment</div>";
  //$('.test').html(html);
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  body,
  html,
  #print-wrappe {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #print-wrapper * {
    visibility: visible;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .my-table {
    border: solid;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="print" id="print">
<div id="print-wrapper">
  <div class="print-heading">My table
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="print-week-heading">Some heading</div>
    <table class="my-table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          A
        </td>
        <td>
          B
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          C
        </td>
        <td>
          D
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

A possible solution to the table being over the content, is to replace `print-weekly-heading` with a `<caption>Some Heading</caption>` as the first child of the table? This snippet shows what I'm trying to achieve, but would require further CSS to make the caption a usable title.

```js
document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //var html = "<div>Test assignment</div>";
  //$('.test').html(html);
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  body,
  html,
  #print-wrappe {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #print-wrapper * {
    visibility: visible;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .my-table {
    border: solid;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="print" id="print">
<div id="print-wrapper">
  <div class="print-heading">My table
  </div>
  <div>
    <table class="my-table">
      <caption>Some heading</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>
          A
        </td>
        <td>
          B
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          C
        </td>
        <td>
          D
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Edit

A third option, is to `display: block` the table cells and float them. This requires prior knowledge of the number of `td`s in the table so you know what `width` to it as. I've also set the table `page-break-before:always` on so that the table takes up a whole page to itself. You can remove this and give the table a height of `calc(100% - 3em);` so that it fits with the headings on the same page as well.

```js
document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //var html = "<div>Test assignment</div>";
  //$('.test').html(html);
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  html,
  body,
  #print-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #print-wrapper * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #print-wrapper>div:nth-child(2) {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .my-table {
    page-break-before: always;
    border: solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 3em);
  }
  .my-table td {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="print" id="print">
<div id="print-wrapper">
  <div class="print-heading">My table
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="print-week-heading">Some heading</div>
    <table class="my-table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          A
        </td>
        <td>
          B
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          C
        </td>
        <td>
          D
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```