# How to center a bootstrap 4 row vertically and horizontally when there are some rows before

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Let's assume we have a main menu and three rows afterwards. The first row should be at the top, the third at the bottom. The second row has to be centered vertically and horizontally.
When you scroll down you should be able to hide the main menu but everything else should fit in the page.

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196587/how-to-center-align-vertically-the-container-in-bootstrap), I know about justify-content-center and I played a bit around with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376558/how-to-fill-100-of-remaining-height). But I can't put it together.
The second row is centered vertically but it stretches the height and it's not correctly centered horizontally anymore.
Here is what I tried:

```css
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100vh; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

html, body, {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.full {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="nav">
         <div class="container-fluid navbar-main">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md no-padding navbar-main">
               <div class="container">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Main menu</a>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                     aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Menü aufklappen">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                     id="navbarSupportedContent">
                     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                           <a class="nav-link" href="/" role="button">Start</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </nav>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col header">
               <span id="score">first row </span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row justify-content-center vertical-center" style="height:100%">
            <!-- div to center -->
            <div class="col-auto">
               <span id="operand1">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
               <span id="operator">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
               <span id="operand2">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
               <span id="operand2">text</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the "col-auto" for all the the divs in the 2nd row.
Have a look at this

```css
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100vh; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

html, body, {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.full {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="nav">
         <div class="container-fluid navbar-main">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md no-padding navbar-main">
               <div class="container">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Main menu</a>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                     aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Menü aufklappen">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                     id="navbarSupportedContent">
                     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                           <a class="nav-link" href="/" role="button">Start</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </nav>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col header">
               <span id="score">first row </span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row justify-content-center vertical-center">
            <!-- div to center -->
            <div class="col-auto">
               <span id="operand1">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
               <span id="operator">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
               <span id="operand2">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
               <span id="operand2">text</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here you were using "col-4" <div class="col-auto">
               <span id="operand2">text</span>
            </div>

Comment: go to the "row justified-content-center" in your code,, then check the 4th div, you used "col-4" but I used "col-auto" for 4th div...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything inside that row with a `div` that has a `class` called `centered`. For example, add position relative to the parent row and add css class:

```
.centered{position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;}
```